# RPC call from non-unity app to unity app

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, rpc, android-networking

I have C#/Android project in Unity Free. I'm going deeper into Networking, unfortunately I cannot use sockets.

I want to send RPC/Msg/TCP from non-Unity "client" app(Android, Desktop, iOS etc.) to Unity "server" app which will trigger something on the side of "server"...

Is it possible? How RPC call look a like, and how to reproduce in different environment?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I believe Unity implements multiplayer networking via RakNet, which offers client libraries for C# and C++. You may be able to get another client to play along with Unity.